# Prime gaps within which every "small" prime appears as a factor: Are there only finitely many? Is this the last one?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, oeis

For a bounded range of positive integers $n,n+1,\ldots,m,$ call a prime number "small" if it does not exceed $\sqrt m,$ so that if one is trying to factor all of these numbers into primes, one need only check "small" primes, and it those don't finish off the factorization, one does one last division, getting a "large" prime.

Now suppose the range is the gap between the $k\text{th}$ and $(k+1)\text{th}$ primes. For large values of $k,$ it is unusual to find *all* of the small primes as factors of numbers within the gap. However, it does happen with the gap between $1327$ and $1361.$ The small primes in that case are the first $11$ primes: $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31.$ All of those are factors of some number in that gap.

I suspect that somewhere in the literature it is proved that for sufficiently large $k,$ this *never* happens. That raises the question of how large is sufficiently large. I won't be surprised if this particular gap is the very last one for which it happens. (Nor will I be greatly surprised if it is not.)

If there are indeed only finitely many such gaps, is there a list of them somewhere? Maybe on OEIS?

Comment: there is no proof, but it is conjectured that the gap after prime $p$  is smaller than $\sqrt p.$ Computer computations suggest that the gap gets much smaller, $g < \log^2 p$ for $p \geq 11$  as far as has been calculated (really really no proof beyond that) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results

Comment: How far up have you looked, Michael? How far beyond $1361$?

Comment: Later thought, the likelihood that some gap,  considerably smaller than $\sqrt p,$  fails your condition, should come under the Erdos-Kac methods. See Kac's little book,  https://bookstore.ams.org/car-12/   where chapter 4  is Primes Play a Game of Chance

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I've looked at a number of examples far beyond that but I've done nothing in a systematic way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted [by Will Jagy in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3324/will-jagy), this is closely related to the size of prime gaps: Any gap of size at least $\sqrt{m}$ has this property.

In fact, every gap with this property has size at least $\sqrt{m}/\log m$: We have $$\prod_{i=n}^{m } i\geq \prod_{\substack{p \leq \sqrt{m}\\  \textrm{prime}}} p$$ and the RHS has size $e^{\sqrt{m}}$ by the prime number theorem while the left hand size $\leq m^{m+1-n}$ so we must have $(m+1-n) \gtrapprox \frac{\sqrt{m}}{\log m}$.

So the conjecture that finitely many of these exist is stronger than the statement that there are finitely many prime gaps of size $\sqrt{m}$ but weaker than the statement that there are finitely many prime gaps of size $\leq (1-o(1))\frac{\sqrt{m}}{\log m}$. It's certainly conjecturally true as even stronger bounds are conjectured, but beyond the reach of proof.

---

From my point of view the remaining thing to do is to shrink the gap between the minimum gap size required for every small prime to appear and the minimum gap size which guarantees that all small primes appear.

To that end, observe that for $p\leq \sqrt{m}$ for the gap to have size $\leq m-n$, we must have $ \left\{ \frac{m}{p}\right\} \leq \frac{m-n}{p}$ so if $p_1 \leq p_2$, the distance from $\frac{m}{p_1} - \frac{m}{p_2} = \frac{m (p_1-p_2)}{p_1p_2} $ to the nearest integer is at most $\frac{m-n}{p_1}$.

The results of Zhang and Maynard on bounded gaps between primes count pairs of primes with bounded gaps in dyadic intervals. I think the same methods without modification count pairs of primes with bounded gaps in slightly smaller intervals, so we can choose $p_1= (1+o(1)) \sqrt{ \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}} $ so that $p_2-p_1=O(1)$. Then $\frac{ m(p_1-p_2)}{p_1p_2}$ will be $1+o(1)$ times a bounded integer times $\sqrt{2}$, so its distance from the nearest integer will be bounded away from $0$ by an absolute constant, so $\frac{m-n}{p_1}$ must be greater than an absolute constant, and thus the gap must be greater than an absolute constant times $\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: Is one of your bottom lines the statement that my guess has not been proved?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The last sentence before the horizontal bar is the statement that your guess has not been proved. This seems to have been implicitly observed by Will Jagy in his comment.

Comment: @WillSawin https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05437

Comment: @mathworker21 Great, that's exactly what's needed for the argument at the end (in fact much stronger).

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to suggest that it is only a conjecture that only finitely many gaps of size${}\ge\sqrt m.$ Is that part of what you meant?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes. I think the reason I didn't say this precisely is that Will Jagy already pointed it out.

Answer (score 2):

Euristically your claim is true: for sufficiently large $n$ one cannot find all small primes in $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$.

Under the assumption of the Cramér conjecture $p_{n+1}-p_n=O((\log p_n)^2)$. If the set of positive integers $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$ contains, as factors, all primes not exceeding $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}$, then all primes in the interval $[ \frac12\sqrt{p_{n+1}},\sqrt{p_{n+1}}]$ must appear as factors of some integers in $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$. But at most two prime factors of $[ \frac12\sqrt{p_{n+1}},\sqrt{p_{n+1}}]$ can appear in each integer of the sequence $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$.

Since there are, roughly speaking, $\frac{\sqrt{p_n}}{2\log{\sqrt{p_n}}}$ primes in $[ \frac12\sqrt{p_{n+1}},\sqrt{p_{n+1}}]$ and the set of integer $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$ can absorbe at most $2(\log p_n)^2$ primes in the interval $[ \frac12\sqrt{p_{n+1}},\sqrt{p_{n+1}}]$, this means that for sufficiently large $n$ one don't find all small primes in  $p_n, p_n+1, p_n+2,\dots, p_{n+1}$.